# String to Date with month in Swedish

Tags: java

I have a String value like `2014-maj-06 11:44:39` which I would like to convert into a Java Date, where the month is stored in Swedish format.

I wonder how the pattern for my simpledateformatter should look like?

Comment: Could you show what you've already tried, and the result? That would make this a better question.

Comment: I was looking at examples here https://stackabuse.com/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-java/ where it says the month(M) could be (May, May, 05) but this is in English.

Comment: Simpledateformat can accept a [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) if I remember, I've never used it so i'm not sure if that's what's needed.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inject your `DateTimeFormatter` with the desired [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-LLL-dd hh:mm:ss", new Locale("sv"))
.parse("2014-maj-06 11:44:39");
```

... will give you (my indents):

```
{SecondOfMinute=39, HourOfAmPm=11, MinuteOfHour=44, NanoOfSecond=0, 
    MilliOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0},
    ISO resolved to 2014-05-06
```

API [here](http://file:///usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

The `Locale` object will work in conjunction with the `LLL` format, which matches the abbreviated textual month form, aka in Swedish, `maj` for May.

**Note**

For Java `< 8`, you can use the same format and `Locale`, and initialize a new `SimpleDateFormat` instead.

Comment: I am still < 8 so could you clearify your suggestion for java 6?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-LLL-dd hh:mm:ss",new Locale("sv"));
          
          Date thedate = format.parse("2014-maj-06 11:44:39"); or?

Comment: @PatrickKwinten yep. The `String` representation of the `Date` will vary as it's not the same APIs as Java 8, but the properties are those.

Comment: @PatrickKwinten For Java 6 & 7, most of the *java.time* functionality was back-ported in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Adding this library to your project is well worth the bother; *vastly* better than using the terrible legacy date-time classes.